# What is the best way to evenly distribute objects to fill a curved space in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, distribute, evenly

I would like to fill this auditorium seating area with chairs (in the editor) and have them all face the same focal point (the stage). I will then be randomly filling the chairs with different people (during runtime). After each run the chairs should stay the same, but the people should be cleared so that during the next run the crowd looks different.

The seating area does not currently have a collider attached to it, and neither do the chairs or people.

[image]

I found this code which has taken care of rotating the chairs so they target the same focal point. But I'm still curious if there are any better methods to do this.

```
//C# Example (LookAtPoint.cs)
using UnityEngine;
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LookAtPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 lookAtPoint = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(lookAtPoint);
    }
}
```

Additional Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can [write a editor script](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html) to automatically place them evenly. In this script,

*I don't handle world and local/model space in following code.* Remember to do it when you need to.

1. Generate parallel rays that come from +y to -y in a grid. The patch size of this grid depends on how big you chair and the mesh(curved space) is. To get a proper patch size. Get the bounding box of a chair(A) and the curved space mesh(B), and then devide them(B/A) and use the result as the patch size.

   ```
   Mesh chairMR;//Mesh of the chair
   Mesh audiMR;//Mesh of the auditorium
   var patchSizeX = audiMR.bounds.size.X;
   var patchSizeZ = audiMR.bounds.size.Z;
   var countX = audiMR.bounds.size.x / chairMR.bounds.size.x;
   var countZ = audiMR.bounds.size.z / chairMR.bounds.size.z;
   ```

   So the number of rays you need to generate is about `countX*countZ`. Patch size is `(patchSizeX, patchSizeZ)`.

   Then, origin points of the rays can be determined:

   ```
   //Generate parallel rays that come form +y to -y.
   List<Ray> rays = new List<Ray>(countX*countZ);
   for(var i=0; i<countX; ++i)
   {
       var x = audiMR.bounds.min.x + i * sizeX + tolerance /*add some tolerance so the placed chairs not intersect each other when rotate them towards the stage*/;
       for(var i=0; i<countZ; ++i)
       {
           var z = audiMR.bounds.min.z + i * sizeZ + tolerance;
           var ray = new Ray(new Vector3(x, 10000, z), Vector3.down);
           //You can also call `Physics.Raycast` here too.
       }
   }
   ```
2. Get postions to place chairs.

   1. attach a MeshCollider to your mesh temporarily
   2. foreach ray, [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) it (you can place some obstacles on places that will not have a chair placed. Set [special layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) for those obstacles.)
   3. get hit point and create a chair at the hit point and rotate it towards the stage
3. Reuse these hit points to place your people at runtime.

   Convert each of them into a model/local space point. And save them into [json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3427520) or asset via serialization for later use at runtime: place people randomly.

Comment: Okay would you recommend generating the rays in the xy-plane or the zy-plane? The picture I've shown is part of a semi circular layout. There are 3 other risers that need to be populated. Also, I'm not sure how to determine the density, are the bounding box of the chair and the curved space mesh vectors? I really appreciate your help, this has been really difficult.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot that shows all of your curved-space mesh?

Comment: The surface I'm placing the chairs on doesn't have a collider (should it?) I like the sound of your method because my end goal is randomly place people in the chairs and having points defined would be ideal. The spline method I've used (see new screenshots) is messy.

Comment: Yes, to use raycast, the mesh should have a collider attached. But I think you need to describe more about what you want and in what kind of environment. Two important aspects: 1. When will these chairs/people be placed? At runtime or just in the editor? 2. Will them be placed again randomly? If so, are both chairs and people be cleared and placed again? At runtime? Please **edit your question** to show us more information.

Comment: Okay done. Just let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this and update you with my results over the next few days!